# Why can't Smart Groups be assigned the Access Control group type?

Tags: smartgroups

I'm using CiviCRM 4.5.8 and WordPress. I want people to only access the data for their state. I was going to use ACL to do that. I set up a smart group for Wisconsin, but there's no check box for Access Control. I can only check Mailing List. What's up with that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

According to a 2007 [forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=1645.0) by Donald Lobo (a CiviCRM founder): For efficiency purposes the acl role needs to be assigned to a static group.

Perhaps the [CiviRules Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) will allow you to add your users to a static group(?)

Comment: I saw that 2007 post when I was googling this. I just wondered if anything had changed since then? I'll check out that extension...thanks!

Comment: This IS supposed to work now: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34981.0

Comment: In fact, I think it does work! I found it helpful to follow the steps found here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15662